# In-App Billing: Error: Your payment could not be processed at this time

Tags: android, in-app-billing

RE: Unable to test in-app purchase via Google Play Store due to In-App Billing: Error: Your payment could not be processed at this time

I have completed an app that uses in-app billing to allow the user to purchase some virtual products within the app. I've followed all the steps outlined in "Testing In-app Purchases Using Your Own Product IDs":

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-real

These are the steps I have taken to test:

1. Uploaded application as a draft to the Developer Console.
2. Added items to the application's product list.
3. Set up Test Google Account
4. Added a Test Google Account to Developer Console
5. Set Up Google Wallet for Test Google Account, Added Payment Method under my name
6. Factory reset of Test Device
7. Restarted device and Signed in with new Test Account
8. Loaded draft apk

When I attempt to purchase an item in the application, Google Wallet responds:

"Error: Your payment could not be processed at this time. You may receive an email asking you to verify your account."

I check my gmail inbox and for each failed purchase I have two emails - the first is an order receipt, and the second is an order cancellation receipt.

I've tried waiting 24, 48 hours and get the same response.

Any ideas on how to resolve this. How else I am supposed to verify that in-app billing will work for my users if I cant even go through the process end-to-end myself.